# How do I use a testfor for Lives?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to see if when a decoy player when it loses its lives and it goes to 0, it will do a testfor and when that is finished it will teleport everyone to the spawn and say "This Team Has Won" (I just need help with the testfor)

Comment: What are you using for "decoy player"s? Are its lives stored in a scoreboard objective?

Comment: Yes What I did is I made decoy players so when a player dies in a team a the decoy player or PrisonersTeam Loses A Life. I want to know to say when A player wins or not. When the lives reach 0 the it says that this player has won. I can do everying I just need the testfor.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, make it that when they die, you have a scoreboard that goes up every death.

```
/scoreboard objectives add {Name} deathCount
```

To test the deaths:

```
/testfor @p[score_Score_min={Lives they have}]
```

Hoped this helped!

EDIT: I hope this is what your after:

/testfor @p[score_Lives_min=0,score_Lives=0]

Comment: I don't understand. I have already have it to where the lives go down when a person in that team dies. I just need to know how to make it so when a team lives reaches 0 it will end the game. That is why i need a testfor. test for the decoy player with 0 lives for that specific team. I plan on making two one for each team.

Comment: Sorta You are going the right way. Just how to change @p Or Player Name to Decoy player name. So Something Like This /testfor PrisonersTeam [whatevergoesinhere]